# Get around involuntary typing of columns in CSV file when using for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am using a CSV file to inject data into my test.

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource( CsvData, CsvDir + "TC177023.csv", "TC177023#csv", SEQ )]
```

The file looks somethings like this: (other strings removed)

```
something,something,Value,something,something,something
,,0xDEADBEEF,,
,,-12,,
,,0,,
,,0,,
,,0,,
```

I have one column that I have integers in and I wanted to extend this to hexadecimals. So I took the value from the column "Value" and instead of casting it to an int

```
int value = (int)TestContext["Value"];
```

I tried to access the string representing the integer

```
string text = TestContext.DataRow["Value"].ToString();
```

But all I got was a empty string. I wont bother you with all I tried to find out what the problem was. I could at least see from inspecting the TestContext object while debugging that the type of the column indeed vas Int32.

In the end I tried to replace the integer values in the column with strings and, lo and behold, I got my hexadecimal value. My conclusion is that, when loading the values, the test framework is "helping" me and sets the type of the column by look on values.

*now to my question:*

Can I set something somewhere to inhibit this behavour so the MS unit test framework does not help me with this ?
I cannot change the framework, I cannot change the int values in that column to something recognised as strings. I am not the end user of the solution so any workarounds would probably make things worse. I just want to get the "raw value" of the "cell" for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated it further and for whose who would have the same question, I write it down here.
And the short answer to my question here is no, I cannot within my limitations.

The long answer is: The test framework is using oledb connection to read from excel and csv files. There is a way to make oledb to accept "mixed values", sending the string  "IMEX = 1" as Extended Properties in the connection string.
Source:
https://yoursandmyideas.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider/
Unfortunatly the connection string is set inside the framework code, at least in the open source version, that is accessable on githug and I haven't found a way smuggle in the string.